# How I can apply Mvvmlight into the VB.Net project.?

Tags: c#, vb.net, integration, mvvm-light

I have tried with vb.net project but it will not allow to access C# View and ViewModel because VB.NET is not ready for MvvmLight.?

So my question is I have existing project into the vb.net and I wanted to know how I can use MvvmLight into the VB.NET>

What I did I had created small addressboll into the C# using MvvmLight pattern and I am trying to integrate this project into my existing VB.NET project but it will not compatible so is there any unique way where I can achieve my MvvmLight pattern.?

Thank you...!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MVVM Light in VB.Net.  C# when compiled to a DLL and referenced in your project can be used used in VB.net.  The reverse would be true of VB.Net DLL's in C#.  That's the goodness of the .NET CLR.

As for the specifics of MVVM Light, install the latest package, http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/installing/ and reference the correct assemblies.

Use the Imports statement to bring the GalaSoft.MVVMLight namespaces into your project.

```
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command

Public Class UseMVVMLightInVB
```